# Where does ELOG messages go?

Tags: c, postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I'm working with a C Library, `librouting_darp.dll` which uses the function `elog` to log debugging messages of its processes. But I don't know where to look for the messages which the function is logging.

Do you know where I can find those messages?

--

Note: I don't know if `elog` is a "C" Function or a "PostgreSql" Function.

[Here](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/darp/extra/darp/src/darp_solver.cpp) you can find the source code which I'm talking about.

I'm using PgAdmin + PostgreSql + PostGis + PgRouting to call this function called DARP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [PostgreSQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/error-message-reporting.html) which supports several debug levels and not all of them are saved by default. You can configure this through log_min_messages setting.

Comment: I've followed your link, and as it says I low the level for the properties to the lowest one 

`begin   
set log_min_error_statement = INFO;   
set log_min_messages = INFO;   
set client_min_messages  = INFO;   
end;`  
  
Eventhough I'm still not getting any of the elog messages specified in the C Library.

Comment: what is the `log_destination`?

Comment: Try with csvlog and/or eventlog: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Comment: No positive results.

This is what I did: 
1) I changed 
log_destination = 'eventlog'

2) Restarted the PostgreSQL server 

3) change again    
log_min_messages = DEBUG5  
client_min_messages = DEBUG5

4) Execute the funtion
I do get all PostgreSQL log messages into the windows viewer BUT still it hasnt show any C Library message yet.

Comment: I tried using others function from another similar library and It did worked! So it seems it's something particular with that library/function. I will try to sort it out (don't have even a clue)

Anyway thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, when building postgresql from source code, the following settings in postgresql.conf enabled the logs for me. The logs are saved within the data directory (run `SHOW data_directory;`) in a folder name specified with the `log_directory` config

```
log_destination = 'syslog'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'log' # Relative to data directory
log_min_messages = log

log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
log_file_mode = 0600
```

Answer (score 0):

If Windows, I'd look in `eventvwr`, the Windows Event Viewer.

I'd also check C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\XXX\data\pg_log

Comment: I've checked them both! And yes, **...data\pg_log** it does save a log, but I don't see the elog messages there. Neither in the eventvwr.